# Loading a web page in Android App

Tags: java, android

I don't know how to access my `index.html` webpage when the app is loaded. Actually on my code I use `file:///android_asset/index.html`, I've tried to load a Google page to test, it works, but it launch the Chrome app...

Here is my code of my `MainActivity.java` :

```
package com.totominc.fr.webapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html"); // error may be here...
    }
}
```

But the error which I got is that it can't find the file `index.html`.

[Here is a screenshot of my project.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCohA.png)

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: You need to put your `index.html` file into your **assets** folder, and not **/res/drawable**.

Comment: your path is not correct... try to put assets and give that path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
file:///Android_res/drawable/index.html
```

As your index html is in drawable folder. this would work

Answer (score 0):

Create your assets folder in `src/main/assets/` and put your index.html there, not inside your drawables. Regarding the page opening in Chrome, try this instead

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    // Changed here
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html"); // error may be here...
}
```

Comment: I have edited my answer regarding where you should place your index.html file. Try it out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your `index.html` file into your **assets** folder, and not **/res/drawable**.

So your `index.html` should be in **/assets/index.html**.